# C++ I/O stream issue: program asks for input twice or work incorrectly

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to write a program that reads input as int from the command line, and if the user enters an int, program prints "Input is " + the number if users enter an incorrect type input, output "wrong input".
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int input;
 cout << "Enter an Int:" << endl;
 cin >> input;

 if (!(cin >> input)) {
  cout << "wrong format input" << endl;
  return 1;
 }

 cout << "input is " << input << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Now with `cin >> input;` (case-1) program asks for **twice** input when enter correct integer; it prints "wrong format input" if user enter '2.2' or 'a'.

Without `cin >> input;` (case-2) program ask for once input when enter correct integer; **but** it prints "input is 2" when user enter '2.2', instead of printing "wrong" message, program prints "Input is 2".

Which part in my code did I make mistake? How can I fix this?

For case-2:
[image]

Comment: Count how many times you use `cin >> input`. That's how many times you'll need to type something.

Comment: `cin >> input` will read in an integer value and stop when it encounters something that can't be part of a valid integer (such as a decimal point). The decimal point and the fractional value remain unread in `cin`.

Comment: If you want to check the input to be valid integer - read it as string and then use stoi function to convert the string to int and also check the whole string was parsed. If part of the string is not processed by stoi function - input is invalid

Comment: Your mistake is using `>>` in order to read a line of input. That's not what the `>>` operator is for. `>>` does not read a line of input. To do that you need to use `std::getline()`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky that's tricky, do i have to use try catch to deal with the exception if input string contains non-numeric character or decimal point such as enter 'a' or '2.2'

Comment: @dreamlax thx a lot, that explain case-2, but how does it work for case 1, if i don't remove the first cin >> input, it creates redundant input request but read whole input regardless of  decimal point

Comment: If a conversion function doesn’t find characters in its string argument that it can convert to a number, it throws `invalid_argument` . If it finds a number that it cannot represent in its target type, it throws `out_of_range` ;

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thx so i should use string for input as Artemy said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample that allows to enter several integers on the same line, but disallows anything else

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    while(std::cin >> input){
        size_t last;
        int res;
        bool good = true;
        try{
            res = std::stoi(input,&last);
        }
        catch(...){
            good = false;
        }
        if(!good || last != input.length()){
            std::cout << "Incorrect input: " << input << ", try again.\n";
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Integer read: " << res << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/***************
Output
$ ./test
2
Integer read: 2
hello
Incorrect input: hello, try again.
2.2
Incorrect input: 2.2, try again.
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Incorrect input: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111, try again.
3 4
Integer read: 3
Integer read: 4
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 ./test
*/
```

Another version - using stringstream

```
    while(std::cin >> input){
        std::istringstream ss(input);
        int res;
        ss >> res;
        if(!ss){
            std::cout << "Incorrect input: " << input << ", try again.\n";
        }
        else{
            char ch = ss.get();//let's check that no more characters left in the string
            if(!ss){
                std::cout << "Integer read: " << res << '\n';
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "Incorrect input: " << input << ", try again.\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if(!(cin >> input)) is the reason for the second input. Just do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int input;
 cout << "Enter an Int:" << endl;
 cin >> input;

 if (cin.fail()) {
  cout << "wrong format input" << endl;
  return 1;
 }

 cout << "input is " << input << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `using namespace std;`